# Is it possible to set product version at build time in a Basic MSI project?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, basic-msi

I have an InstallScript project that I'm looking at manually recreating as a Basic MSI project. For the InstallScript project, we obtain the product version at build time through the following mechanism:

- Ant does all the compiling, testing, etc. and during this process obtains a build version number.
- Ant calls IsCmdBld.exe, passing the build version as an environment variable.
- Installshield has an "Environment"-type path variable configured, which picks up the build version.
- This path variable is specified in the General Information -> Product Version field.

Unfortunately, it looks like the Basic MSI project does not allow path variables in the Product Version field.

Does this mean the product version has to always be manually modified before each build with a Basic MSI project? Or is there a different way to pass the version to InstallShield?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following command for **Basic MSI** and **InstallScript MSI**:

```
ISCmdBld.exe -y "1.0.5"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
IsCmdBld.exe -z "ProductVersion=1.0.0002"
```